# _CastError was thrown building Builder: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

The following error was thrown while building `Builder` method of my state class in my project:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _AddNewStoryScreenState.didChangeDependencies `package:database/screen/add_new_story_screen.dart:63`
```

The Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../provider/item.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider/items.dart';

class AddNewStoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/AddNewStory';

  const AddNewStoryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddNewStoryScreen> createState() => _AddNewStoryScreenState();
}

class _AddNewStoryScreenState extends State<AddNewStoryScreen> {
  final _authorFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _contentFocusNode = FocusNode();
 
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late int selectedRadio;

  setSelectedRadio(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadio = val;
    });
  }

  var _isLoading = false;

  var _editedItem = Item(
    author: '',
    category: '',
    content: '',
    id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    startColor: '',
    endColor: '',
   
    title: '',
  
  );

  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'content': '',
    'category': '',
    'author': '',
  };

  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedRadio = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final itemId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (itemId != null) {
        _editedItem =
            Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false).findById(itemId);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedItem.title.toString(),
          'content': _editedItem.content.toString(),
          'category': _editedItem.category.toString(),
          'author': _editedItem.author.toString(),
        };
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authorFocusNode.dispose();

    _contentFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _addItem(Item item) {
    const url = 'https://*******.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    return http
        .post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: json.encode({
        'title': item.title,
        'author': item.author,
        'content': item.content,
      
        'id': DateTime.now().toString(),
        'startColor': item.startColor,
        'endColor': item.endColor,
        'category': item.category,
      }),
    )
        .then((response) {
      _editedItem = Item(
        title: _editedItem.title,
        author: _editedItem.author,
        category: _editedItem.category,
        content: _editedItem.content,
        id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
        startColor: _editedItem.startColor,
        endColor: _editedItem.endColor,
      
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _form.currentState?.validate();

    if (isValid == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (_editedItem.id != null) {
      await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
          .updateItem(_editedItem.id.toString(), _editedItem);
    } else {
      try {
        _addItem(_editedItem).then((_) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        });
        _form.currentState?.save();
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
         await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
        .addProduct(_editedItem);
      } catch (error) {
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('An error occured!'),
            content: const Text('Something went wrong.'),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('Okay'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      
    }



    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add New Story'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
              onPressed: _saveForm,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _form,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'عنوان داستان',
                          ),
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'عنوان داستان را وارد کنید';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(_authorFocusNode);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _editedItem = Item(
                              title: value,
                              author: _editedItem.author,
                              category: _editedItem.category,
                              content: _editedItem.content,
                              id: _editedItem.id,
                              startColor: _editedItem.startColor,
                              endColor: _editedItem.endColor,
                            
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _initValues['author'],
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'اسم نویسنده',
                          ),
                          focusNode: _authorFocusNode,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'اسم نویسنده را وارد کنید';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(_contentFocusNode);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _editedItem = Item(
                              title: _editedItem.title,
                              author: value,
                              category: _editedItem.category,
                              content: _editedItem.content,
                              id: _editedItem.id,
                              startColor: _editedItem.startColor,
                              endColor: _editedItem.endColor,
                            
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _initValues['content'],
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'متن داستان',
                          ),
                          maxLines: 3,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          focusNode: _contentFocusNode,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'متن داستان را وارد کنید';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            _editedItem = Item(
                              title: _editedItem.title,
                              author: _editedItem.author,
                              category: _editedItem.category,
                              content: value,
                              id: _editedItem.id,
                              startColor: _editedItem.startColor,
                              endColor: _editedItem.endColor,
                               
                            );
                          },
                        
                        ),
                        
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            
                            Card(
                              child: RadioListTile(
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setSelectedRadio(val as int);
                                  _editedItem = Item(
                                    title: _editedItem.title,
                                    author: _editedItem.author,
                                    category: 'story',
                                    content: _editedItem.content,
                                    id: _editedItem.id,
                                    startColor: Color(0xffFF5B95).toString(),
                                    endColor: Color(0xffF8556D).toString(),
                                   
                                  );
                                },
                                value: 1,
                                title: const Text('تخیلی'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              child: RadioListTile(
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setSelectedRadio(val as int);
                                  _editedItem = Item(
                                    title: _editedItem.title,
                                    author: _editedItem.author,
                                    category: 'narrative',
                                    content: _editedItem.content,
                                    id: _editedItem.id,
                                    startColor: Color(0xff6DC8F3).toString(),
                                    endColor: Color(0xff73A1F9).toString(),
                                    
                                  );
                                },
                                value: 2,
                                title: const Text('حکایت'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              child: RadioListTile(
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setSelectedRadio(val as int);
                                  _editedItem = Item(
                                    title: _editedItem.title,
                                    author: _editedItem.author,
                                    category: 'qurani',
                                    content: _editedItem.content,
                                    id: _editedItem.id,
                                    startColor: Color(0xffD76EF5).toString(),
                                    endColor: Color(0xff8F7AFE).toString(),
                                
                                  );
                                },
                                value: 3,
                                title: const Text('قرآنی'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              child: RadioListTile(
                                groupValue: selectedRadio,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setSelectedRadio(val as int);
                                  _editedItem = Item(
                                    title: _editedItem.title,
                                    author: _editedItem.author,
                                    category: 'success',
                                    content: _editedItem.content,
                                    id: _editedItem.id,
                                    startColor: Color(0xffFFB157).toString(),
                                    endColor: Color(0xffFFA057).toString(),
                                 
                                  );
                                },
                                value: 4,
                                title: const Text('از تاریخ'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }


 
}
```

Also, when I hover over the `build(BuildContext context)` method, I see this warining:

```
The declaration 'build' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'build'.dartunused_element
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the 'build' method or change UnimplementedError() to other code.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

and change

```
ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String
```

to

```
ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this "build referencing error"
move all your code in the newly generated build method by vs code and remove your build method declaration , it will be fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).